ROS2 Custom message package is not compiling. Can you see what I am doing wrong?
I have added all the information that might be relevant - it is a lot!  The boilerplate required to create a package seems overwhelming to a beginner.
This is the error from colcon:
colcon build --symlink-install
[0.335s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.ament:The path '/home/paul/Documents/ROS2/ros2_ws/install/face_recog' in the environment variable AMENT_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist
Starting >>> vision_interfaces
--- stderr: vision_interfaces                             
In file included from /home/paul/Documents/ROS2/ros2_ws/build/vision_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/detections__functions.h:19,
                 from /home/paul/Documents/ROS2/ros2_ws/build/vision_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/detections__functions.c:4:
/home/paul/Documents/ROS2/ros2_ws/build/vision_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/detections__struct.h:23:10: fatal error: vision_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.h: No such file or directory
   23 | #include "vision_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/build.make:135: CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/detections__functions.c.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:213: CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /home/paul/Documents/ROS2/ros2_ws/build/vision_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/vision_interfaces/msg/detections__type_support.cpp:7:
/home/paul/Documents/ROS2/ros2_ws/build/vision_interfaces/rosidl_generator_cpp/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/detections__struct.hpp:21:10: fatal error: vision_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp: No such file or directory
   21 | #include "vision_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dir/build.make:104: CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/vision_interfaces/msg/detections__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:395: CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
In file included from /home/paul/Documents/ROS2/ros2_ws/build/vision_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/detections__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.hpp:11,
                 from /home/paul/Documents/ROS2/ros2_ws/build/vision_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/dds_fastrtps/detections__type_support.cpp:4:
/home/paul/Documents/ROS2/ros2_ws/build/vision_interfaces/rosidl_generator_cpp/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/detections__struct.hpp:21:10: fatal error: vision_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp: No such file or directory
   21 | #include "vision_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dir/build.make:112: CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/dds_fastrtps/detections__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:343: CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
In file included from /home/paul/Documents/ROS2/ros2_ws/build/vision_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/detections__type_support.cpp:12:
/home/paul/Documents/ROS2/ros2_ws/build/vision_interfaces/rosidl_generator_cpp/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/detections__struct.hpp:21:10: fatal error: vision_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp: No such file or directory
   21 | #include "vision_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dir/build.make:112: CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dir/rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp/vision_interfaces/msg/detail/detections__type_support.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:369: CMakeFiles/vision_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< vision_interfaces [0.44s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.74s]
  1 package failed: vision_interfaces
  1 package had stderr output: vision_interfaces
  1 package not processed

The top-level directory structure is:
ros2_ws
    face_recog
       data
       resource
       test
       face_recog (this contains python source code)
    vision_interfaces
       include
       msg (this contains Detection.msg and Detections.msg)

vision interfaces Cmake.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(vision_interfaces)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/Detection.msg"
  "msg/Detections.msg"
 )
 
ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)

ament_package()

vision_interfaces package.xml:
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
<name>vision_interfaces</name>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<description>TODO: Package description</description>
<maintainer email="33916898+elpidiovaldez@users.noreply.github.com">paul</maintainer>
<license>Apache-2.0</license>
<buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>
<exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
<member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
<export>
<build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
</export>
</package>

face_recog package.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>face_recog</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="33916898+elpidiovaldez@users.noreply.github.com">paul</maintainer>
  <license>Apache-2.0</license>

  <depend>rclpy</depend>
  <depend>sensor_msgs</depend>
  <depend>vision_interfaces</depend>
  <depend>cv2</depend>
  <depend>cv_bridge</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

The import statements in face_recog/live_face_recog.py:
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

import cv2
import torch
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN, extract_face, InceptionResnetV1
from cv_bridge import CvBridge,CvBridgeError
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from vision_interfaces.msg import Detections
from vision_interfaces.msg import Detection


I finally solved the problem thanks to finding this message.
The problem was due to using 'Header' from std_msgs in my custom message.  The corrected package and Cmake files are:
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(vision_interfaces)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/Detection.msg"
  "msg/Detections.msg"
  DEPENDENCIES std_msgs
 )
 
ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)

ament_package()

package.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>vision_interfaces</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="33916898+elpidiovaldez@users.noreply.github.com">paul</maintainer>
  <license>Apache-2.0</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
  <depend>std_msgs</depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

I also had to modify the message definition that used 'Header' to explicitly state that it was from std_msgs:
Detections.msg
#A list of objects detected in an image
std_msgs/Header header
std_msgs/Header image_header
Detection[] detections

I think that the boilerplate required to do anything in ROS is a major barrier to its usage.  I have spent far more time trying to sort out the boiler plate than I have spent writing useful code.  I think that some gui based code generator could make the system massively more accessible.  Given the sophistication of other ROS tools (like rviz, gazebo etc), I am surprised nobody has done this.
